# Where can I find d3dcompiler_43.dll and corresponding lib files?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-10

I am trying to make a "hack" for a really old game. My dll injector does not resolve dll import and everything work just fine except `D3DCompile` function that is causing access violation. After long debugging session I figured out that it is causing this error because my code is referencing to `d3dcompiler_47.dll` but game has only `d3dcompiler_43.dll` in it. My question is where can I get corresponding libraries that will (after including to project) use `d3dcompiler_43.dll`?

Only thing that I have found was a dll `D3DCompiler_43.dll` which was inside `Jun2010_D3DCompiler_43_x64.cab`.

Where can I find the header files and lib files for this d3d compiler version?

EDIT: Found all files in Unreal Engine source code.

Answer (score 1):

D3DCompiler is normally part of the windows SDK, which can be found at [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive). Note that if your game is old enough you may need to download an older version of the SDK (if it uses Direct3D 9 or earlier for example) but I can't tell you exactly how far back you would need to go.

Comment: Note that #43 is from the legacy DirectX SDK. For more information, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/).

Comment: Note that for #43 D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX11, and D3DCompiler, there is a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) package you can use instead of the legacy DirectX SDK. It also provides a side-by-side REDIST so you can avoid the need to use legacy DirectSetup as well. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/).